# Can't decode my HTML entities

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-entities

I am storing my raw html like this...

```
nl2br(htmlentities($this->input->post('raw_html')))
```

In my database the data looks like this...

```
&amp;lt;ul&amp;gt;                                 &amp;lt;li&amp;gt;Improve our understanding of this issue&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;                                 &amp;lt;li&amp;gt;Strengthen your listening and writing skills&amp;lt;/li&amp;gt;                             &amp;lt;/ul&amp;gt;
```

When I try and display the markup from my database I use this:

```
echo html_entity_decode($html_from_db, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

But I get this output being shown in the browser:

```
<ul> <li>Improve our understanding of this issue</li> <li>Strengthen your listening and writing skills</li> </ul>
Lesson name
```

And html entities are shown in my source code... so no entities are being decoded.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Why? It works perfectly: for example ´<´ is converted to `&amp;lt;` and then back. Of course, it does not remove your HTML tags.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear, it is not converted back... the HTML is shown in the browser, if I look at my source code I am still getting my entities and they are not converted to HTML, that is why the actual HTML tags appear in my browser.

Comment: `&amp;lt;li&amp;gt;` is actually double encoded, it decodes to `&lt;li&gt`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php has the flag that could prevent double encoding but I suggest you ensure you're not getting encoded HTML before encoding it yourself

Comment: Not related, but you really should store the data as it is and only encode it when you need to output it and then you encode for that specific medium. And using `nl2br` *after* encoding is also not a very good idea as you are introducing html back into your encoded string.

Comment: Not sure I understand, so I should not store markup in the database?

Comment: You should not encode your string for html output when you want to store it in a database.

Comment: Agreeing to @apokryfos, it is actually double encoded, and it would be better to get rid of the second encoding than to decode it twice. But, as jeroen stated, there is no need to encode HTML for storing in the database.

Comment: Yep, your data double encoded. Of cause you can also double decode it with 
`echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks for the advice... so just store the raw HTML in... then I don't need `htmlentities()` or `html_entity_decode()`?

Comment: some of CMS/Frameworks works with encoded data. You have to look at your code, probably you are really encode it twice or with some additional parameter

Comment: There might be the odd edge-case where you'll want to encode the HTML when you're outputting it back to the browser; such as into a `<textarea>` in a WYSIWYG editor in a CMS; but yup - there's no reason not to store the raw HTML in the database - though you may want to purify it first : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst the database has no problem handling arbitrary strings as long as they are **escaped** (note esacping is not html entity encoding/deconding). You should store data as you receive them and encode entities only when you want to make sure you're not injecting HTML where you don't want to.

Comment: No idea how it is being double encoded... I am taking my raw HTML from my textarea input then applying htmlentities() once before inserting into the database... perhaps codeigniter applies that already to all text inputs?

Comment: not sure. Ok then try to insert without encoding

Comment: Inserting without encoding works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably when you're using encode with `htmlentities` you encoded it twice. See at function params:

```
function htmlentities ($string, $quote_style = null, $charset = null, $double_encode = true) {}
```

So you can try this:

```
nl2br(htmlentities($this->input->post('raw_html'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false))
```

Comment: I tried this, no difference... however just removing the encoding/decoding functions and storing the raw HTML solved my issues... thanks for the help.

Comment: Added example. Try to use with params

Comment: You da boss! Works wonderfully! Next time I will consult the manual FIRST.